# PowerShell set-itemproperty permission denied

Tags: powershell

Pls, How i have to solve this problème?

```
# set disable:
If ($Set_value -eq 0){ (set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\RadioManagement\SystemRadioState").'1'}
Else { (set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\RadioManagement\SystemRadioState").'0'}

# set enable:
If ($Set_value -eq 1){ (set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\RadioManagement\SystemRadioState").'0'}
Else { (set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\RadioManagement\SystemRadioState").'1'}
```

Thanks for your help
@

Comment: You are commenting _"No echo"_... If you want `Set-ItemProperty` to return something, you need to append switch `-PassThru` to it. See [Set-ItemProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty?view=powershell-7.2#outputs) Your question wasn't about _echo_, but about toggling a number in the registry, which is exactly what my code does.

Answer (score 0):

Arenas,

Since your $Set_Value can only be 1 or 0 you only need one if test. Also since the value for that item is a Reg_DWORD you want a number as the value not a string.

As to the permission denied you need to run as Administrator. If that doesn't work you need to see your admin to get your access permissions changed.

Edited: As per Theo's post below I added the -Name parameter. I saw a post where it said it was unnecessary for the Default value but obviously that was incorrect!

```
$RegPath = "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\RadioManagement\SystemRadioState"

If ($Set_value -eq 0 ){ set-ItemProperty -Path "$RegPath" -Name '(Default)' -Value 1 }
Else                  { set-ItemProperty -Path "$RegPath" -Name '(Default)' -Value 0 }
```

Comment: Sir, please download the error.txt: https://arenas.pagesperso-orange.fr/mail/error.txt | thank's Sir

Comment: Messieurs, Many thank to you. # Theo i dont get any echo :( - R-Geek: I dont have any echo :( # PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $RegPath = "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\RadioManagement\SystemRadioState"
$set_value = 0
If ($Set_value -eq 0 ){ set-ItemProperty -Path "$RegPath" -Name '(Default)' -Value 1 }
Else                  { set-ItemProperty -Path "$RegPath" -Name '(Default)' -Value 0 }

Comment: Only manuelle. :(

Comment: The last file txt: https://arenas.pagesperso-orange.fr/mail/error.txt Thanks

Comment: I dont have any error, but no the right answer :( - .visible = $false is not ok

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code, starting with the fact that you do have a complete registry path to the **`registry KEY`**, but do not supply the entry **Name** to update.

The second thing is that you need to run it with Admin permissions, since you are trying to alter a registry vaue in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` hive.

You do not say what is in variable `$Set_value`, but I can imagine this exercise is to toggle the default value in the registry path from `1` to `0` and vice-versa ?

In that case try

```
$regPath   = 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\RadioManagement\SystemRadioState'
# assuming you obtained the value in this variable like this:
$Set_value = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $regPath -Name '(Default)'

# show the current status
$airplaneMode = if ($Set_value) {'Enabled'} else {'Disabled'}
Write-Host "Airplane mode is currently $airplaneMode"

# now toggle it. To make sure the value can only be 1 or 0, I'm using some [math] static methods:
$Set_value = 1 - [math]::Abs([math]::Sign($Set_value))  # 1 --> 0 and 0 --> 1

# and set the new default value
Set-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name '(Default)' -Value $Set_value -Type DWord

# show the updated status
$airplaneMode = if ($Set_value) {'Enabled'} else {'Disabled'}
Write-Host "Airplane mode is now $airplaneMode"
```

Comment: Sir, the toggle is OK! but i don't have any echo.. I run this script "run as admin" also i clean up all register. the '(default)' is ok. Type REG_Dword and 0x00000001(1) or (0). I have virus in my Pc? Many thank's to you.

Comment: @Arenas You probably need to restart the computer for it to pick up the changes. I'm on mobile now so I cannot check right now..

Comment: Thank's for your reply. Yesterday i have restart my pc. No résultat.. Sir you no, you can have PowerShell up to 7 on your Mobile! You need Samsung 64 bits to do ... Wath is your country?